# Remove non-functioning launcher icon

Tags: skype, gnome-shell, .desktop, activities-overview

I had two versions of skype installed: one from Skype (package skypeforlinux) and one using snap package in Ubuntu 18.04 Gnome. I removed the snap version but an empty icon in the launcher remains. /usr/share/applications/ contains only skypeforlinux.desktop. ~/.local/share/applications/ is empty. How can I get rid of the empty icon?

[image]